# Delete a directory inside a container

Tags: lxc, lxd

```
# lxc exec mycontainer rm -r /home/myuser/mydir
```

gives me

```
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -r
```

```
# lxc exec mycontainer "bash -c 'rm /home/myuser/mydir -r'"
```

just silently exits without removing the directory.

How can I delete a directory within the container?

Comment: Also `lxc file` does not have a delete command

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker, you can:

```
docker container exec mycontainer -it bash
```

or

```
docker container exec mycontainer -it /bin/bash
```

Enter inside the container and remove the directory or, depending of how you've built it, you can run the command directly:

```
docker container exec mycontainer sh -c 'rm /path'
```

By the way, I guess nobody uses lxc directly, only through Docker, Rancher or other container orchestration software.

Comment: Well I can understand the reasoning, but we are using LXD directly (not LXC). Number of questions related to LXC/LXD definitely shows that "nobody" is slightly exaggerated. Docker: 640 questions, LXC: 380, LXD: 210.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--`

```
lxc exec mycontainer -- rm -r /home/myuser/mydir
```